# Default buildDir for kotlin projects

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I'm trying to add documentation to my project with dokka https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html

I'm not quite able to figure out where the `javadocs` are located after doing a successful `./gradlew build.`

It says there they should be in `$buildDir/javadoc` but I'm not sure where `buidlDir` is pointing to.

My build.gradle file is this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.4'

    }

}
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'
     id 'org.jetbrains.dokka' version '0.9.18'

    // id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "1.23.1"

}

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
}


group 'com.github.me.dynamik'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'




mainClassName = 'com.github.me.dynamik.interpreter.MainEntryKt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/hotkeytlt/maven") }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }

}
configurations {
    ktlint
}
dependencies {

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile 'com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse-jvm:0.4.0-alpha-3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    implementation 'com.github.ajalt:clikt:1.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.0'


}



compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.github.me.dynamik.interpreter.MainEntryKt'
    }
}

test {

    // Always run tests, even when nothing changed.
    dependsOn 'cleanTest'

    // Show test results.
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

I'd love a pointer or two in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gradle the project property `buildDir` points by default to the subdirectory `build` of your project directory.

The dokka output directory `javadoc` may be missing in `buildDir` because the `dokka` task has never run before. Your build.gradle file seems not to have any dependencies on the `dokka` task or its output, so it isn't triggered when you're running `build` or `assemble` tasks. You can try running it explicitly: `./gradlew dokka` or add a dependency on that task to some other lifecycle task, e.g

```
assemble.dependsOn(dokka)
```